# File Open/Save dialog boxes hang infinitely

Tags: macos, finder, icloud, filesystem, performance

Today for the first time I have this issue where *any* app showing a file browser (load/save) dialog box hangs indefinitely until I kill it.

The Finder works just fine however. I can browse everything, iCloud and network locations included, there. I haven't found a common point in the traces where the apps hang, so I'm not sure what might be the cause.

Here's the relevant sample from TeXShop when I tried to save a document (before that I had to kill VLC twice after accidentally hitting Cmd-O; opening a video in a different way was no problem though. At that point I thought it might just be a VLC bug, but I've now discovered it's system-wide)

```
Thread_976321   DispatchQueue_1: com.apple.main-thread  (serial)
???  (in TeXShop)  load address 0x10d205000 + 0x2164  [0x10d207164]
NSApplicationMain  (in AppKit) + 1832  [0x7fff8e730a14]
-[NSApplication run]  (in AppKit) + 711  [0x7fff8e745608]
???  (in TeXShop)  load address 0x10d205000 + 0xad20d  [0x10d2b220d]
-[NSApplication sendEvent:]  (in AppKit) + 3937  [0x7fff8e8b935b]
-[NSApplication _handleKeyEquivalent:]  (in AppKit) + 920  [0x7fff8e935fb5]
-[NSMenu performKeyEquivalent:]  (in AppKit) + 359  [0x7fff8e939a1d]
_os_activity_initiate  (in libsystem_trace.dylib) + 75  [0x7fff91fe3cd7]
-[NSCarbonMenuImpl performActionWithHighlightingForItemAtIndex:]  (in AppKit) + 114  [0x7fff8e93a9dc]
-[NSMenuItem _corePerformAction]  (in AppKit) + 382  [0x7fff8e93acbe]
-[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:]  (in AppKit) + 452  [0x7fff8e920b71]
_os_activity_initiate  (in libsystem_trace.dylib) + 75  [0x7fff91fe3cd7]
???  (in TeXShop)  load address 0x10d205000 + 0x8a3dd  [0x10d28f3dd]
-[NSDocument saveDocumentWithDelegate:didSaveSelector:contextInfo:]  (in AppKit) + 128  [0x7fff8eb71b36]
-[NSDocument performActivityWithSynchronousWaiting:usingBlock:cancellationHandler:]  (in AppKit) + 179  [0x7fff8eb66978]
-[NSDocument _processActivity:blockingMainThread:]  (in AppKit) + 1773  [0x7fff8eb659f8]
__67-[NSDocument saveDocumentWithDelegate:didSaveSelector:contextInfo:]_block_invoke  (in AppKit) + 353  [0x7fff8eb71ca4]
-[NSDocument _commitEditingWithDelegate:didSomethingSelector:contextInfo:thenContinue:]  (in AppKit) + 138  [0x7fff8eba65ad]
-[NSDocument _commitEditingThenContinue:]  (in AppKit) + 495  [0x7fff8eba63fa]
__67-[NSDocument saveDocumentWithDelegate:didSaveSelector:contextInfo:]_block_invoke_2  (in AppKit) + 498  [0x7fff8eb71ea5]
-[NSDocument continueActivityUsingBlock:]  (in AppKit) + 323  [0x7fff8eb66cda]
__67-[NSDocument saveDocumentWithDelegate:didSaveSelector:contextInfo:]_block_invoke_3  (in AppKit) + 159  [0x7fff8eb720d0]
???  (in TeXShop)  load address 0x10d205000 + 0x8713d  [0x10d28c13d]
-[NSDocument runModalSavePanelForSaveOperation:delegate:didSaveSelector:contextInfo:]  (in AppKit) + 137  [0x7fff8eb74042]
-[NSDocument performActivityWithSynchronousWaiting:usingBlock:cancellationHandler:]  (in AppKit) + 61  [0x7fff8eb66902]
__85-[NSDocument runModalSavePanelForSaveOperation:delegate:didSaveSelector:contextInfo:]_block_invoke  (in AppKit) + 361  [0x7fff8eb741ba]
-[NSDocument _commitEditingWithDelegate:didSomethingSelector:contextInfo:thenContinue:]  (in AppKit) + 138  [0x7fff8eba65ad]
-[NSDocument _commitEditingThenContinue:]  (in AppKit) + 495  [0x7fff8eba63fa]
__85-[NSDocument runModalSavePanelForSaveOperation:delegate:didSaveSelector:contextInfo:]_block_invoke_2  (in AppKit) + 312  [0x7fff8eb74301]
-[NSDocument _preparedSavePanelForOperation:]  (in AppKit) + 256  [0x7fff8eb73922]
+[NSSavePanel _crunchyRawUnbonedPanel]  (in AppKit) + 208  [0x7fff8ecf7659]
-[NSSavePanel initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:]  (in AppKit) + 631  [0x7fff8ecf817a]
-[NSSavePanel _initPanelCommon]  (in AppKit) + 466  [0x7fff8ecf8e30]
-[NSSavePanel(NSSavePanelLayout) _layoutViewsVerticallyAndResizeWindowToLastExpandedSize:accessoryViewHeight:]  (in AppKit) + 5147  [0x7fff8ed0dd35]
-[NSBox setContentView:]  (in AppKit) + 81  [0x7fff8eab3f4a]
-[NSView addSubview:]  (in AppKit) + 463  [0x7fff8e766f83]
-[NSView _setWindow:]  (in AppKit) + 3174  [0x7fff8e769c33]
__21-[NSView _setWindow:]_block_invoke733  (in AppKit) + 169  [0x7fff8ee5a054]
-[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]  (in CoreFoundation) + 313  [0x7fff8de1da89]
__53-[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke  (in CoreFoundation) + 133  [0x7fff8de1e385]
-[NSView _setWindow:]  (in AppKit) + 257  [0x7fff8e7690ce]
-[FIFinderView viewWillMoveToWindow:]  (in FinderKit) + 320  [0x7fff9244778e]
-[FIFinderViewGutsController prepareToShow]  (in FinderKit) + 146  [0x7fff9243e8ff]
-[FIFinderViewGutsController forceContainerToExist]  (in FinderKit) + 146  [0x7fff9243de8b]
-[FIFinderViewGutsController _internalSetTargetPath:withViewStyle:]  (in FinderKit) + 912  [0x7fff9244213e]
-[FI_TBrowserContainerController initWithWindowState:targetPath:containerDelegate:]  (in FinderKit) + 459  [0x7fff924b68bb]
-[FI_TBrowserContainerController configureContainerWithState:]  (in FinderKit) + 41  [0x7fff924b71f5]
-[FI_TBrowserContainerController configurePersistentViewsWithState:]  (in FinderKit) + 338  [0x7fff924bc12f]
-[FI_TSidebarSplitterController configureSidebar:setSplitterPosition:]  (in FinderKit) + 398  [0x7fff92449e67]
-[NSSplitView setPosition:ofDividerAtIndex:]  (in AppKit) + 174  [0x7fff8e8a90b1]
-[NSSplitView _resultOfDividerDragToLeadingPosition:withParams:]  (in AppKit) + 420  [0x7fff8ed61c9b]
-[FI_TSidebarSplitterController splitView:constrainSplitPosition:ofSubviewAt:]  (in FinderKit) + 84  [0x7fff9244ab2f]
-[FI_TSidebarViewController optimalWidth]  (in FinderKit) + 31  [0x7fff9244d2c6]
-[FI_TSidebarViewController optimalWidthNoScrollbar]  (in FinderKit) + 665  [0x7fff9244ce41]
-[FI_TSidebarView preparedCellAtColumn:row:]  (in FinderKit) + 53  [0x7fff9245ea03]
-[NSOutlineView preparedCellAtColumn:row:]  (in AppKit) + 52  [0x7fff8ea0fdff]
-[NSTableView preparedCellAtColumn:row:]  (in AppKit) + 414  [0x7fff8e9ba7be]
-[FI_TSidebarViewController(DataSource) outlineView:objectValueForTableColumn:byItem:]  (in FinderKit) + 68  [0x7fff92450386]
-[FI_TSidebarItemCell name]  (in FinderKit) + 109  [0x7fff924549e9]
TSidebarController::NameForNode(TFENode const&)  (in FinderKit) + 120  [0x7fff9245b5ec]
TFENode::Name() const  (in FinderKit) + 45  [0x7fff922ead9f]
TFENodeFactory::GetOriginalCloudDocsNode()  (in FinderKit) + 21  [0x7fff922f607d]
TLazyInitializer<TFENode, TiCloudNodeFetcher>::Get(TLazyInitializer<TFENode, TiCloudNodeFetcher>*)  (in FinderKit) + 222  [0x7fff922f6732]
TiCloudNodeFetcher::Fetch()  (in FinderKit) + 122  [0x7fff922f6af8]
TFENode::TFENode(__CFURL const*)  (in FinderKit) + 36  [0x7fff922e5716]
NodeCopyFromURL  (in DesktopServicesPriv) + 188  [0x7fff9206f547]
TNode::GetNodeFromURL(__CFURL const* const&, TNodePtr&, NodeRequestOptions)  (in DesktopServicesPriv) + 507  [0x7fff920a8c37]
TNode::GetNodeFromPathName(TPathName const&, TNodePtr&, NodeRequestOptions)  (in DesktopServicesPriv) + 822  [0x7fff920a4e0c]
TNode::FindChild(TUString const&, bool) const  (in DesktopServicesPriv) + 811  [0x7fff9206673b]
TFSInfo::Initialize(TCountedPtr<TFSInfo> const&, TUString const&)  (in DesktopServicesPriv) + 124  [0x7fff92066cbc]
TFSInfo::Initialize(__CFURL const*, bool, bool)  (in DesktopServicesPriv) + 304  [0x7fff92114246]
TFSInfo::FetchProperties()  (in DesktopServicesPriv) + 1700  [0x7fff92061ce8]
CFURLCopyResourcePropertyForKey  (in CoreFoundation) + 123  [0x7fff8ddf806b]
_FSURLCopyResourcePropertyForKeyInternal(__CFURL const*, __CFString const*, void*, void*, __CFError**, unsigned char)  (in CoreServicesInternal) + 211  [0x7fff93b910ea]
prepareValuesForBitmap(__CFURL const*, __FileCache*, _FilePropertyBitmap*, __CFError**)  (in CoreServicesInternal) + 227  [0x7fff93b9374f]
LSPropertyProviderPrepareValues(__CFURL const*, __FileCache*, __CFString const* const*, void const**, long, void const*, __CFError**)  (in LaunchServices) + 53  [0x7fff96c1d2e6]
prepareDistinctLocalizedNameValue(__CFURL const*, __FileCache*, __CFError**)  (in LaunchServices) + 92  [0x7fff96c28284]
prepareAttributeValueForKey(__CFURL const*, __FileCache*, __CFString const*, void const**, __CFError**)  (in LaunchServices) + 178  [0x7fff96c242de]
_LSCopyItemAttributeForRefInfoWithOptions  (in LaunchServices) + 129  [0x7fff96c243e3]
_LSCopyItemAttributesForRefInfoWithOptionsCommon(LSExtendedFSRefInfo const*, unsigned int, __CFArray const*, unsigned int, __CFDictionary const**)  (in LaunchServices) + 367  [0x7fff96c9db23]
_LSCopyNodeAttributes  (in LaunchServices) + 377  [0x7fff96c9698d]
_LSCopyNodeAttribute_DisplayNameIfDifferentFromFSNameWithLanguage(LSNodeAttributeStateCache*, __CFString const*)  (in LaunchServices) + 56  [0x7fff96c98096]
_LSCopyBRDisplayNameForNode  (in LaunchServices) + 83  [0x7fff96c8d91c]
BRCopyDisplayNameForContainerAtURL  (in CloudDocs) + 223  [0x7fff8d3ceff6]
-[BRContainerCache containerByID:forURL:]  (in CloudDocs) + 225  [0x7fff8d3db7d3]
-[BRXPCSyncProxy resultWithTimeout:]  (in CloudDocs) + 57  [0x7fff8d3cd9fa]
_dispatch_group_wait_slow  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 218  [0x7fff9b3beb9c]
semaphore_wait_trap  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 10  [0x7fff92a1351a]
```

Here's the sample from Numbers.app, which hangs immediately after starting (because it starts opening the file browser). Oddly there's no mention of CloudDocs here.

```
start  (in libdyld.dylib) + 1  [0x7fff8f3235c9]
NSApplicationMain  (in AppKit) + 1832  [0x7fff8e730a14]
-[NSApplication run]  (in AppKit) + 594  [0x7fff8e745593]
-[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:]  (in AppKit) + 194  [0x7fff8e751730]
_DPSNextEvent  (in AppKit) + 2665  [0x7fff8e752626]
AEProcessAppleEvent  (in HIToolbox) + 56  [0x7fff93c81a2e]
aeProcessAppleEvent  (in AE) + 295  [0x7fff94fa3623]
dispatchEventAndSendReply(AEDesc const*, AEDesc*)  (in AE) + 31  [0x7fff94fa3719]
aeDispatchAppleEvent(AEDesc const*, AEDesc*, unsigned int, unsigned char*)  (in AE) + 531  [0x7fff94fa399c]
_NSAppleEventManagerGenericHandler  (in Foundation) + 102  [0x7fff93766059]
-[NSAppleEventManager dispatchRawAppleEvent:withRawReply:handlerRefCon:]  (in Foundation) + 290  [0x7fff937661e8]
-[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleCoreEvent:withReplyEvent:]  (in AppKit) + 244  [0x7fff8e755f75]
-[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleAEOpenEvent:]  (in AppKit) + 561  [0x7fff8e756529]
-[NSApplication _reopenWindowsAsNecessaryIncludingRestorableState:registeringAsReady:completionHandler:]  (in AppKit) + 412  [0x7fff8e7567f7]
-[NSPersistentUIManager restoreAllPersistentStateRegisteringAsReadyWhenDone:completionHandler:]  (in AppKit) + 406  [0x7fff8e757551]
-[NSPersistentUIRestorer restoreStateFromRecords:usingDelegate:completionHandler:]  (in AppKit) + 2118  [0x7fff8e757eec]
-[NSPersistentUIRestorer finishedRestoringWindowsWithZOrder:completionHandler:]  (in AppKit) + 1745  [0x7fff8e8a6f74]
-[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) _autoreopenDocumentsIgnoringExpendable:withCompletionHandler:]  (in AppKit) + 798  [0x7fff8ebb92f1]
__97-[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) _autoreopenDocumentsIgnoringExpendable:withCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke_3  (in AppKit) + 124  [0x7fff8ebb98e9]
-[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) _autoreopenDocumentsFromRecords:withCompletionHandler:]  (in AppKit) + 540  [0x7fff8ebb8454]
__90-[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) _autoreopenDocumentsFromRecords:withCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke1716  (in AppKit) + 625  [0x7fff8ebb8886]
__90-[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) _autoreopenDocumentsFromRecords:withCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke1716  (in AppKit) + 467  [0x7fff8ebb87e8]
__90-[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) _autoreopenDocumentsFromRecords:withCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke  (in AppKit) + 66  [0x7fff8ebb8526]
__95-[NSPersistentUIManager restoreAllPersistentStateRegisteringAsReadyWhenDone:completionHandler:]_block_invoke557  (in AppKit) + 37  [0x7fff8efd9ee0]
__58-[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleAEOpenEvent:]_block_invoke  (in AppKit) + 252  [0x7fff8e8ae741]
-[NSApplication _doOpenUntitled]  (in AppKit) + 290  [0x7fff8e9750c4]
-[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) _showOpenPanel]  (in AppKit) + 63  [0x7fff8ebb9a96]
???  (in Numbers)  load address 0x10711e000 + 0x3a56e1  [0x1074c36e1]
-[NSDocumentController openDocument:]  (in AppKit) + 354  [0x7fff8ebaa817]
-[NSDocumentController beginOpenPanelWithCompletionHandler:]  (in AppKit) + 85  [0x7fff8ebaacbf]
-[NSDocumentController _setupOpenPanel]  (in AppKit) + 37  [0x7fff8ebaa8b8]
+[NSSavePanel _crunchyRawUnbonedPanel]  (in AppKit) + 74  [0x7fff8ecf75d3]
+[NSSavePanel newRemotePanel]  (in AppKit) + 301  [0x7fff8ecf7541]
-[NSVBSavePanel init]  (in AppKit) + 303  [0x7fff8efaac9d]
-[NSRemoteViewBase bridge]  (in ViewBridge) + 207  [0x7fff95267668]
-[NSRemoteViewBase viewServiceMarshalProxy:withErrorHandler:]  (in ViewBridge) + 88  [0x7fff95270fe3]
-[NSWindowCentricRemoteView advanceToConfigPhase]  (in ViewBridge) + 947  [0x7fff9527ed3b]
-[NSRemoteViewBase advanceToConfigPhase:awaitingWindowRights:]  (in ViewBridge) + 1277  [0x7fff952707cd]
-[NSCFRunLoopSemaphore wait]  (in ViewBridge) + 429  [0x7fff952623c9]
invokeRunLoopInModeUntil  (in ViewBridge) + 87  [0x7fff9528ac27]
invokeUntil  (in ViewBridge) + 199  [0x7fff9528abae]
__invokeRunLoopInModeUntil_block_invoke  (in ViewBridge) + 20  [0x7fff9528ac42]
CFRunLoopRunSpecific  (in CoreFoundation) + 296  [0x7fff8de0c858]
__CFRunLoopRun  (in CoreFoundation) + 1371  [0x7fff8de0cffb]
__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort  (in CoreFoundation) + 212  [0x7fff8de0db34]
mach_msg  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 55  [0x7fff92a1264f]
mach_msg_trap  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 10  [0x7fff92a134de]
```

Running 10.10.2 (14C1514)

```
$ uname -v
Darwin Kernel Version 14.1.0: Thu Feb 26 19:26:47 PST 2015; root:xnu-2782.10.73~1/RELEASE_X86_64
```

Any ideas?

---

It disappeared after restarting, but of course that doesn't mean it won't return…

Comment: I have the exact same issue on 10.11.6. It usually appears from time to time every few weeks and only a reboot solves it. Strange thing.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Yosemite? Am finding installing the Betas clear up these problems that are so hard to trace.

Comment: it's 10.10.2 14C1514, the current released version

Comment: The usual diagnostics done? Do you own Disk Warrior? An SMC reset for your machine, a startup from the Recovery Disk (partition) & run Disk Utility from there ... but I repeat, often a reinstall solves.

Comment: The problem is that it didn't even appear again after a reboot… so I wouldn't be able to tell if any more drastic method would fix the root cause. Updated 10.10.3 now, I'll just have to wait and see if it appears again I guess.

Comment: I have the exact same issue on 10.11.6. It usually appears from time to time every few weeks and only a reboot solves it. Strange thing.